# Como ordenar una lista en Python y que quede como Diccionario

Tags: python, python-3.7

Tengo esta lista

```
datos = ["juan", 18, "masculino", "camilo", 25, "masculino", "luisa", 23, "femenino"]
```

Y deseo que quede asi:

```
diccio = [
{
"nombre": "juan",
"edad": 18,
"sexo": "masculio"
},
{
"nombre": "camilo",
"edad": 25,
"sexo": "masculino"
},
{
"nombre": "luisa",
"edad": 23,
"sexo": "femenio"
}
```

]

La idea principal es crear el json a partir de la lista.
De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: si la lista no cambia y se mantiene el orden (nombre,edad,sexo) si se podria

Comment: Entonces, ¿qué pides? ¿Generar el JSON o el diccionario?

Comment: @Christian la lista es dinámica, pero se conserva la misma estructura de 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para generar lo pedido puedes usar:

```
salida = [dict(nombre=datos[i], edad=datos[i+1], sexo=datos[i+2]) for i in range(0,len(datos),3)]
```

Esta es una comprensión de lista. En cada iteración se genera un diccionario poblado con tres valores (nombre, edad y sexo) que se obtienen desde la lista de datos.

La variable `i` usada para indexar se avanza de tres en tres, para ir pasando de persona en persona.

**Demo**

```
datos = ["juan", 18, "masculino", "camilo", 25, "masculino", "luisa", 23, "femenino"]
salida = [dict(nombre=datos[i], edad=datos[i+1], sexo=datos[i+2]) for i in range(0,len(datos),3)]
print(salida)
```

produce

```
[{'nombre': 'juan', 'edad': 18, 'sexo': 'masculino'}, {'nombre': 'camilo', 'edad': 25, 'sexo': 'masculino'}, {'nombre': 'luisa', 'edad': 23, 'sexo': 'femenino'}]
```

Comment: Excelente!!... justo lo que necesitaba. Analizando el código que presenta. Quisiera preguntarle donde puedo aprender esa manera de escribir código en una sola línea.

Comment: @juenDiegoGuzman. Se llama [comprensión de listas](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=comprensi%C3%B3n#list-comprehensions). Es una manera compacta de crear una lista. Es una herramienta fundamental en Python.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque la respuesta aceptada es perfecta, sólo para mostrar un truquillo adicional que puede ser útil en esta pregunta y en otros casos, añado lo siguiente.

En la [documentación del módulo `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) hay al final unos cuantos ejemplos entre los cuales aparece una joyita: la implementación de una función llamada `grouper()` que he usado en múltiples ocasiones (y que creo que debería formar parte de ese módulo, para no tener que volver a implementarla cada vez...)

Es una función que recibe un iterable y te devuelve otro iterable, que permite ir obteniendo grupos de N elementos consecutivos del iterable original. Es decir, si el iterable original son los números del 1 al 9 y hacemos `N=3` iremos obteniendo los grupos (1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9).

En la implementación que se da en ese ejemplo se tiene en cuenta también si el número de elementos de la lista no es múltiplo de N y permite especificar un valor de relleno para ese caso. Ya que en este caso no necesitamos eso, proporciono aquí una versión simplificada de `grouper()` que no usa valores de relleno:

```
def grouper(iterable, n):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip(*args)
```

La implementación de esta función parece "magia negra". Si hay interés (en los comentarios) podría explicarla con más detalle, pero llevará su tiempo.

El caso es que, gracias a esta función, la comprensión de listas que genera los diccionarios buscados puede escribirse de una forma más pythónica, sin tener que usar índices de arrays:

```
salida = [dict(nombre=nom, edad=ed, sexo=s) for nom,ed,s in grouper(datos, 3)]
```

Y el resultado es:

```
[{'edad': 18, 'nombre': 'juan', 'sexo': 'masculino'},
 {'edad': 25, 'nombre': 'camilo', 'sexo': 'masculino'},
 {'edad': 23, 'nombre': 'luisa', 'sexo': 'femenino'}]
```

Comment: A veces me sorprende todo lo que sabes

Comment: Existe la posibilidad de hacer una validación en el campo de sexo?. Que si el nombre es carmela, este sea de sexo "indefinido"

Comment: `salida = [dict(nombre=nom, edad=ed, sexo="indefinido" if nom=="carmela" else s) for nom,ed,s in grouper(datos, 3)]` ignoraría lo que hay en el sexo de carmela (de todas las carmelas que hubiere), cambiándolo por "indefinido"

Comment: No me funciono, sale el sexo femenino. El sexo de carmela por defecto es femenino en la lista pero quiero que cambie al momento de crear "salida"

Comment: Como aparece el nombre "carmela" en tu lista? Así, simplemente "carmela" y en minúsculas? En ese caso debería funcionar. Si en cambio aparece algo como "Carmela Gomez", entonces la comparación debería ser más compleja, por ejemplo `if nom.lower().startswith("carmela")`

Comment: El nombre de la lista es "carmenal sanchez", todo en minúsculas, pero al hacer la comparación siempre se ejecuta lo que va en la parte de else

Comment: Es que "carmenal" no es lo mismo que "carmela" :-) Y además la comparación `==` solo es cierta si coincide el texto completo. Para ver solo la primera palabra haz lo de `startswith()`

Comment: Perdón me equivoqué escribiendo el nombre es "carmela sanchez"

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124772/discussion-between-juen-diego-guzman-and-abulafia).